# Two XML elements with different types repeated unbounded times in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

Suppose I use a sequence of `a` and `b` elems. `a` has a type `aType` and `b` has a type `bType`.

```
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="a" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element ref="b" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>

...

<xs:element name="a" type="aType" abstract="true"/>
<xs:element name="b" type="bType" abstract="true"/>
```

If I write an XML doc with sequence which has both type elems of `aType` and `bType`, I get an error. Is it possible to allow in sequence to use any number of elements of two types?  What I want to allow is something like this:

```
 <seq><a/><a/><b/><a/><b/><b/></seq>
```

Comment: Did you tried **xs:choice**? You should add an example of a xml file.

Comment: Yes, It does not work.

Comment: My problem is that I need to have mixed elements of two types in sequence and number of those elements is unlimited.

Comment: Like this: `<seq><a/><a/><b/><a/><b/><b/></seq>`

Comment: You should edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, eliminate `abstract="true"` if you want to instantiate `a` and `b` in your document.

Then, place the `maxOccurs="unbounded"` on `xs:choice`:

```
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element ref="a"/>
    <xs:element ref="b"/>
</xs:choice>
```

to allow `a` and `b` will be allowed to appear repeatedly such as you show in your comment:

```
<a/><a/><b/><a/><b/><b/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The content model you show should match any sequence of one or more elements substitutable for an `a` element, followed by one or more elements substitutable for `b`.

You say, however, that you want to match a sequence of `a` and `b` elements, intermingled.  At least two things in your current declaration will need to change, then:

- If `a` and `b` elements should be allowed to appear in valid document,s then they are not abstract; you should stop saying that they are.
- If a sequence like `<a/><a/><b/>` in the input may validly be followed by more `a` and `b` elements, then the sequence defined by the `xsd:sequence` element needs to be allowed to repeat; changing `xsd:sequence/@maxOccurs` to an integer greater than one, or to `unbounded`, will be necessary.
- If the intermingled set of `a` and `b` elements can start with a `b`, or end with an `a`, then you need to allow the individual elements in the content model to match zero elements in the instance, thus:

  ```
  <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element ref="a" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element ref="b" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  ```

  This is equivalent to the content model already suggested by kjhughes; for the language they both recognize, most readers will find a repeating choice clearer than a repeating sequence all of whose members are optional.